# Why do I have water constantly flowing from my well pump?

Tags: well-pump

My house is on well water and I have great pressure from the well. I've noticed that the well pump kicks on quite frequently and that there is a pipe coming from the pump that has water constantly flowing from it.

What is this pipe for and why would it have water constantly flowing from it?

Comment: I've reworded your question in an effort to make it a bit easier to understand. Please ensure that I haven't significantly changed the intent of what you're asking. Also, a picture of the pump and the pipe would probably be helpful, just to give context.

Comment: It is probably a vent pipe and you have good water pressure flowing into the well from the ground.

Comment: It could be a broken pipe or a faucet that is turned on some place. 
on our 1930 home a faucet was turned on for several weeks it was not until it finally turned into a spring 60’ away from the house we found a pipe that had been abandoned prior to us buying the place. 
it used to have a mother in law unit out there, we had good pressure but our pump was cycling quite often , our neighbors told us about the trailer when I had dug up the area looking for the leak.

Comment: Please [edit] to add a picture or pictures of the pump and "pipe with water constantly flowing"